# Does anyone know how to make this upload img function compatible with an older version of reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to using reactJS (and JS in general). I am trying to add a new function to an existing project but it is not compatible because the react dependency is 16.13.1 and does not use hooks apparently. It doesn't accept useState() in the version of the project.

```
function App() {
 const [file, setFile] = useState(); // storing the uploaded file
 function handleChange(e) { // function to handle the file upload
 console.log(e.target.files);
 setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  }

 return (
 <div className="App">
 <h2>Add Image:</h2>
 <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
 <img src={file} />

 </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to make this compatible with that dependency but I have had no luck with my attempts yet. does anyone know how to make it compatible or any resources that can help? sorry if this is an obvious question, I still have a lot to learn! thank you!

What I've tried so far:

```
class uploadImage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            subMenuOpen: false,
            file: null 
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            file: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
        })
    }
render () {
  return (
      <div className="App">
          <h2>Add Image:</h2>
          <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
          <img src={file} />

      </div>

  );
}}
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe you should convert your function into `Class Component`

try change `<img src={file} />` to `<img src={this.state.file} />`

`<input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />` to `<input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Comment: thanks for responding, I tried that but it still gives me error that the handleChange and file are not defined

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: yes! I edited the post to include what i tried (at the bottom)

Comment: try change  <img src={file} /> to <img src={this.state.file} />

Comment: and  <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} /> should be  <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />